# How can I plot pixel grid using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

```
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(10, "Spectral")))
usamap <- map_data("state")    
ggplot(data=all_data,aes(x=col,y=row,color=m)) + 
      geom_point()+
      scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Flashiness",colours = myPalette(10), limits=c(0,1))+
      geom_polygon( data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),size=0.3, colour="black",fill=NA)+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(line = element_blank())+
      theme(legend.position = c(.93,.20),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#854440"))+
      ggsave("test.png",width=10, height=8,dpi=300)
```

Gives me this plot

[image]

However, I want to have pixels/tiles, instead of dots with the tiles/pixels touching each other. Something of this nature.

[image]

How can I do this? I tried using geom_raster, but I couldn't make it work. Here is the new code:

```
ggplot(all_data) +
  geom_raster(aes(x=col, y=row))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Flashiness",colours = myPalette(100), limits=c(0,1))+
  ggsave("test_pixel.png",width=10, height=8,dpi=300)
```

And the new figure is not in color and also there are gaps between the boxes.

[image]

Full dataset: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrpgk3uqx945hgf/temp.csv?dl=0`

Data preview:

```
dput(head(all_data,10))

structure(list(row = c(48.16, 48.33, 48.15, 48.1, 48.18, 48.14, 
48.23, 48.22, 48.18, 48.14), col = c(-124.7, -124.69, -124.69, 
-124.69, -124.68, -124.68, -124.67, -124.67, -124.67, -124.67
), m = c(0.4713, 0.8998, 0.4891, 0.8418, 0.7998, 0.5292, 0.8115, 
0.8826, 1, 0.5716), flagar = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L), flagk = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), flagsi = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), flags2o = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), flagap = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), flagmt = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), flagcn = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), flagkf = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), flagrd = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), flagrv = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 2L), flagpt = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
)), .Names = c("row", "col", "m", "flagar", "flagk", "flagsi", 
"flags2o", "flagap", "flagmt", "flagcn", "flagkf", "flagrd", 
"flagrv", "flagpt"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What does "couldn't make it work" mean? Did it give you errors? Crash your machine? Not look like what you expected? (If not what you expected how did it differ from those expectations?)

Comment: If your data isn't prebinned into rectangles, maybe you want [`stat_bin_2d`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_bin2d.html)?

Comment: And since I'm too lazy to download a CSV from dropbox, is your data regularly spaced? Is it set up from one row to define a tile in your desired output? Or will there need to be binning?

Comment: @Gregor Thanks. I have updated the code I tried and the new plot. I am not sure what regularly spaced means. But one lat-long combination is tied to one value, which (should) represents a 1 kmx1km pixel.

Comment: In your `geom_raster` version, you don't have a mapping for `fill`. Does it work if you do `geom_raster(aes(x=col, y=row, fill = column_you_want_to_color_by))`?

Comment: As for "gaps between the boxes", my guess it that's data that you don't have. So the question remains of what you want to do in that case.

Comment: And if you want a 1km x 1km grid to be drawn the same size in the south as in the north you might need to use `coord_map` with an equal-area projection (maybe Albers?).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do spatial interpolation from point to raster grid. Using the posted data

```
    library(gstat)
    library(sp)
    library(maptools)
    library(viridis)

    # Create a spatial object
    coordinates(dat) = ~x + y

    # Define the extent for spatial interpolation
    x.range <- c(min(dat$x)-0.0125, max(dat$x)+0.0125)
    y.range <- c(min(dat$y)-0.0125, max(dat$y)+0.0125)

    # Create desired grid
    grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 0.0125), 
                       y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 0.0125))   
    coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
    gridded(grd) <- TRUE

    # Interpolate using Inverse Distance Weighted 
    idw <- idw(formula = m ~ 1, locations = dat, newdata = grd)  
    # Output clean up
    idw.output = as.data.frame(idw)
    names(idw.output)[1:3] <- c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Flashiness")

    # Plot
    p1 <- ggplot() + geom_tile(data = idw.output, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = Flashiness)) +
      scale_fill_viridis() + geom_point(data = all_data, aes(x = col, y = row, size = m), shape = 21, colour = "red") +
      scale_size_continuous(name = "") +
      theme_bw()
    p1
```

Result:

[image]

More information in this [post](http://www.geo.ut.ee/aasa/LOOM02331/R_idw_interpolation.html)